# remove 3rd party folders on iPhone

Tags: iphone, directory, jailbreak

I cannot get to remove 3rd party folders I created some time ago.
I have a jailbroken iPhone 3G. I already tried removing springboard but to no avail. What can I do apart from unjailbreaking it?

(it says that as a user without reputation I cannot post images...)

[edit]
errors added : 
http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/9184/img1107.png 
As you can see it's some third party app folder but I have not identified which one
[/edit]

Comment: upload to another site and post a link

Comment: Here is the screenshot!                                         http://img577.imageshack.us/img577/9184/img1107.png                          As you can see it's some third party app folder but I have not identified which one :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ssh into your jailbroken iphone and remove folders that you don't need.  Obviously, be very careful :)

Comment: Great, I will try to find out how to do it and proceed with the same!